# Swift - Append object: array index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift

When I try to add an item to my array it gives me and EXC BAD INSTRUCTION error and it says

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

That is the code:

```
var tabelle : [[Actions]] = [[]]

func doSomething() {

    var results = self.fetch()

    var oldProjektName: String = results[0].projektName
    var count: Int = 0

    for item in results {
        if oldProjektName == item.projektName {
           tabelle[count].append(item)               
        } else {
            count++
            tabelle[count].append(item)
        }
        oldProjektName = item.projektName
    }
}
```

As long as count = 0 it does not give me an error but when count = 1 then the app crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an array with one element: `var tabelle : [[Actions]] = [[]]`
That is why tabelle[0] is working.

You need to append another array to tabelle before you can use `tabelle[1]`

Comment: Thanks!! Changing table[count].append(item) in the else statement to var array : [Actions] = [item]; tabelle.append(array) solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Try

`var tabelle = [[Actions]](())`